# Error when using "importAgent" interface of dialogflow (node.js)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am using Dialogflow client on my Node.js server to import-agent using .zip file which I got from exporting agent through dialogflow console.
This is the implementation -

```
const dialogflow = require("dialogflow");
const fs = require("fs");

const zipFile = "./exported_agent.zip";
const credentials = require("./credentials.json");

async function importAgent() { 
  try {
    // converting zip file to base64 format
    const base64ZipFile = await fs.readFileSync(zipFile).toString("base64");

    const client = new dialogflow.v2.AgentsClient({
      credentials,
      agentContent: base64ZipFile,
    });

    const formattedParent = client.projectPath("[PROJECT-ID]");

    [operation] = await client.importAgent({parent: formattedParent});
    [response] = await operation.promise();
    
    console.log(response)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

importAgent()
```

But I am facing this error

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: com.google.apps.framework.request.BadRequestException: Invalid agent zip. Missing required json file agent.json
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/home/ddark/Projects/IntentEntityApiTaskDialogflow/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/ddark/Projects/IntentEntityApiTaskDialogflow/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:175:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/ddark/Projects/IntentEntityApiTaskDialogflow/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:341:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/ddark/Projects/IntentEntityApiTaskDialogflow/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:304:181)
    at Http2CallStream.outputStatus (/home/ddark/Projects/IntentEntityApiTaskDialogflow/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:116:74)
    at Http2CallStream.maybeOutputStatus (/home/ddark/Projects/IntentEntityApiTaskDialogflow/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:155:22)
    at Http2CallStream.endCall (/home/ddark/Projects/IntentEntityApiTaskDialogflow/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:141:18)
    at Http2CallStream.handleTrailers (/home/ddark/Projects/IntentEntityApiTaskDialogflow/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:273:14)
    at ClientHttp2Stream.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at emit (internal/http2/core.js:291:8) {
  code: 3,
  details: 'com.google.apps.framework.request.BadRequestException: Invalid agent zip. Missing required json file agent.json',
  metadata: Metadata {
    internalRepr: Map(1) { 'grpc-server-stats-bin' => [Array] },
    options: {}
  }
}
```

On unzipping the .zip file, I can clearly see agent.json file.
I have tried directly importing-agent (using same .zip file) through dialogflow console, it is working fine. But it is showing above error when I am trying to do it with the dialogflow client.
I am following [this](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/dialogflow/0.8.x/v2.AgentsClient).

I appreciate any ideas on how can get this working again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is move the `agentContent` setting from your `.AgentsClient()` call to your `.importAgent()` call - [the example in those docs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/dialogflow/0.8.x/v2.AgentsClient#importAgent) is incredibly bad, as it never shows actually setting `agentContent` or `agentUri` in the `importAgent` call, despite one of them being required!

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it is working fine. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: No problem! If this worked for you, please mark my answer as correct to help others with similar issues ☺